# Clojure: Convert hash-maps key strings to keywords?

Tags: clojure

I'm pulling data from Redis using Aleph:

```
(apply hash-map @(@r [:hgetall (key-medication id)]))
```

The problem is this data comes back with strings for keys, for ex:

```
({"name" "Tylenol", "how" "instructions"})
```

When I need it to be:

> ({:name "Tylenol", :how "instructions})

I was previously creating a new map via:

> { :name (m "name"), :how (m "how")}

But this is inefficient for a large amount of keys.

If there a function that does this? Or do I have to loop through each?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a handy function called [keyword](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/keyword) that converts Strings into the appropriate keywords:

```
(keyword "foo")
=> :foo
```

So it's just a case of transforming all the keys in your map using this function.

I'd probably use a list comprehension with destructuring to do this, something like:

```
(into {} 
  (for [[k v] my-map] 
    [(keyword k) v]))
```

Comment: Yeah looks like basic iteration is the easiest solution, was checking if there was a standard function for maps. But its not hard to abstract that. Thanks

Comment: There is a standard function (in the core libs) that will do it, see my answer below

Answer (score 94):

You can also use the `clojure.walk` library to achieve the desired result with the function `keywordize-keys`

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(keywordize-keys {"name" "Tylenol", "how" "instructions"})
;=> {:name "Tylenol", :how "instructions"}
```

This will walk the map recursively as well so it will "keywordize" keys in nested map too

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk/keywordize-keys

Comment: Most importantly, this works for nested maps!

Answer (score 9):

I agree with djhworld, `clojure.walk/keywordize-keys` is what you want.

It's worth peeking at the source code of `clojure.walk/keywordize-keys`:

```
(defn keywordize-keys
  "Recursively transforms all map keys from strings to keywords."
  [m]
  (let [f (fn [[k v]] (if (string? k) [(keyword k) v] [k v]))]
    (clojure.walk/postwalk (fn [x] (if (map? x) (into {} (map f x)) x)) m)))
```

The inverse transform is sometimes handy for java interop:

```
(defn stringify-keys
  "Recursively transforms all map keys from keywords to strings."
  [m]
  (let [f (fn [[k v]] (if (keyword? k) [(name k) v] [k v]))]
    (clojure.walk/postwalk (fn [x] (if (map? x) (into {} (map f x)) x)) m)))
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it is worth noting that, if the incoming data is `json` and you are using `clojure.data.json`, you can specify both a `key-fn` and a `value-fn` for manipulating results on parsing the string ([docs](https://github.com/clojure/data.json)) -

```
;; Examples from the docs

(ns example
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))


(json/read-str "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}" :key-fn keyword) 
;;=> {:a 1, :b 2}

(json/read-str "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}" :key-fn #(keyword "com.example" %))
;;=> {:com.example/a 1, :com.example/b 2}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this very elegantly using `zipmap`:

```
(defn modify-keys [f m] (zipmap (map f (keys m)) (vals m)))
(modify-keys keyword {"name" "Tylenol", "how" "instructions"})
; {:how "instructions", :name "Tylenol"}
```

Basically, `zipmap` allows to create a map by specifying keys and values separately.

Comment: are keys and vals guaranteed to be in the same order?

Comment: Not sure. I don't know how to check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772384/clojures-maps-are-keys-and-vals-in-same-order

Comment: Clojure doc states that (keys map) and (vals map) function results are ordered with the same order as the (seq map) function. Thus, by associativity, they all have the same order. :) @gtrak

Comment: This is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Using the `keyword` function and `reduce-kv`.

If I have a map e.g.

```
 (def test-map {"key1" "val1" "key2" "val2"}
```

I can do

```
(reduce-kv 
     (fn [m k v] 
        (assoc m (keyword k) v)) 
      {} test-map)

 => {:key1 "val1" :key2 "val2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I second @mikera's [`into` based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406251/2311375). Alternatively, not the most concise but, another option using assoc+dissoc/reduce would be:

```
(reduce #(dissoc (assoc %1 (keyword %2) (get %1 %2)) %2) my-map (keys may-map))
```